# Equivalent of lightbox2 syntax

Tags: 8

I've been using this syntax for years for images in articles :

```
<a href="../img1" rel="lightbox2">  <img src="../img1"   >    </a>
```

Now this Lightbox2 is gone in D8, what will be the equivalent code in D8 Colorbox?

The following code does not open Colorbox:

```
<a href="/sites/default/files/inline-images/otp.PNG" class="colorbox"><img alt="Enter Otp" data-entity-type="file" data-entity-uuid="fea8df0c-09bc-4119-839a-b1d5be551b6a" height="148" src="/sites/default/files/inline-images/otp.PNG" width="302" /></a>
```

I've checked properly and Colorbox library is correctly installed. Though Iam unable to locate Colorbox JQuery library in page after disabling JS aggregation and clearing cache.

Comment: Read the docs first (it's in there), ask here if you get stuck somewhere implementing it

Comment: Here is one [example](https://www.drupal.org/node/1971564#comment-9983061)  but it does not work in the first photo  of [this page](https://www.accountrecovery.in/how-download-e-aadhaar-online)  which already has colorbox class applied.

Comment: @Clive can you please show where it is in the docs?